# How to create retro style containers in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, user-interface

[image]

How do I create borders like the one present in the image, I am building a retro-style app and I want to know how to give containers pixelated borders.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple approach**:

Use an image as button inside your app (i suggest you to use a SVG image to achieve this result. Flutter doesn't support it natively but you can use this package: [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg).

**Advanced approach**:

You can use [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) to draw any custom shape and detect gesture events. This is a more difficult approach but lets you have a full control over your shape (you can also import and use SVGs inside the `CustomPainter`'s canvas).

Comment: if you want a custom shape, "flutter" way is to extend `ShapeBorder`, not `CustomPainter` - example implementations include: `CircleBorder`, `RoundedRectangleBorder`, `StadiumBorder` etc

Comment: Yes this is of course another valid solution, my goal was to give a fast and generic overview of different solutions. Can i ask you why you say that this is the "Flutter" way? I saw a lot of different docs and CustomPainter seems to be the most used widget to create custom shapes (like buttons). If there's somenthing in the official doc which suggest that your solution is the favorite, i'd like to check it out to improve my knowledge :) thanks

Comment: check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle/shape.html - this property defines standard button shape, btw it is used in many places like `Material.shape`, `Card.shape` etc, moreover if you set for example `Material.shape` to `CircleBorder` and then on some event rebuild your page with `RoundedRectangleBorder` you will see the the miracle of morphing the shape from circle to rect, magic! ;-)

Comment: you can run this simple gist https://gist.github.com/pskink/adf730167a48b750a81f1dd197309312 which uses a general purpose `PathBuilderBorder` class that lets you create some nice shape related effects